# using FIND command to find two string from one line with cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file

How to detect the following string from file safely with FIND (cmd.exe default commands), while the name minnie can be anything?  its just that FROM: line has me@my.com on it.

```
From: "Minnie" <me@my.com>
```

it should not be mixed to this TO line :

```
To: <me@my.com>
```

e.g. this batch file row does not work properly :

```
find "me@my.com" abc.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `findstr` instead of `find` which has more advanced capabilities, like regular expression matching.

```
findstr /r /c:"^From:.*<me@my.com>" test.txt
```

will find the specified e-mail address only when the line starts with "From:".

`findstr` is also included by default at least since Windows 2000.

Answer (score 4):

Try two pipelined find commands, like this:

```
find "me@my.com" abc.txt | find "From:"
```

The former searches for all lines containing "me@my.com" and the latter filters them to leave only those lines that contain "From:".

Comment: Wow, Windows supports command pipelining? Learn something new every day! :)

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you're going to be able to accomplish that with *find*, since *find* only looks for a literal match and has no ability to use wildcards or regular expressions.

If you have the option, you can install the UnxUtils package and use grep to do it. It's a port of common Unix Utilities to Win32. You can find it at: [http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/][1]

You'd then issue a grep command like this:

```
grep "From.*me\@my\.com" abc.txt
```

Hope that helps!